# Already open UDP port origin app in Android

Tags: android, udp, native, firewall, sip

Happy to asking my 1st question in this large community.

In Android, I need a way to find out the app-UDPport binding.
The problem is that I cant use the UDP:5060 in Grandstream Wave Lite (SIP client), perhaps because an other app has occupied this port.

First, I tried to "force stop" some communicating apps, even the native sip client.
Second, I installed an app that records in a text box the incoming traffic in specific UDP ports. SIP INVITE messages can appear in free ports eg 5061.

No problem to use for SIP a port different from 5060, but I would like to know if there is an occupation from specific app or a restriction from the Android OS in my current configuration.

I imagine that there isn't an external way of finding open UDP ports in a host because incomming traffic dont require responce. You can have a UDP port as (non-deaf but) mute listener.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.